# curl с большим количеством редиректов

Tags: bash, curl

Есть **curl:**

```
curl -I -L http://example/DataController/live/
```

В нём есть

```
Location: http://example/DataController/live/?page=1
```

затем

```
Location: http://example/DataController/live/?page=2
```

и т. д.

На 50-том перенаправлении обваливается.
**Как решить проблему?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы убрать лимит, используйте опцию `--max-redirs -1`

Вот, что говорит [документация](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--max-redirs):

> `--max-redirs <num>`
>
> (HTTP) Set maximum number of redirection-followings allowed. When -L,
>   --location is used, is used to prevent curl from following redirections "in absurdum". By default, the limit is set to 50
>   redirections. Set this option to -1 to make it unlimited.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Comment: Супер, работает!